# Prove range of values for d for polynomial of degree 3

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

The following question is from a worksheet on polynomials.

The polynomial $x^3 + cx + d=0$ has a solution when $x=d$. Prove that $d$ is the only solution provided $-2 < d < 2 $, $d ≠ 0$

My initial approach to this was through long substitution by factor $(x-d)$, solve for the remainder which would equal zero and find the range of values for d. This only provided $d(d^2+(c+1)) = 0$. Provided $d ≠ 0$, I assumed the square would be the only solution, so using the discriminant, $D = 0$, solved for c to arrive at $c = -1$. This obviously gave $d^3 = 0$ which is not a possible solution. This also uses $d ≠ 0$ without any reason given in my working and is only an assumption.

Could anyone attempt to work through this proof, to arrive at the inequalities and for why $d ≠ 0$?

Comment: As piquito indicated, this question is flawed.  $\quad$ Your conclusion of $d^3 = 0$ is flawed. You're not trying to solve the equation. What you have, is that for the fixed value of $d$, $d^3 + cd + d = 0 $, so the correct conclusion is that $d^2 = -(c+1)$.

Comment: The other roots for $x^3+cx+d$, are of form $\alpha, -1/\alpha$ (by Vieta for the product) and either of the remaining Vieta relations give $ \alpha^2+d\alpha-1=0 \implies \alpha=\frac12(-d\pm\sqrt{d^2+4})$. Hence no value of $d$ seems to restrict $\alpha$ from being real.  You may want to recheck your equation for a sign error or something similar.

Comment: (Contd...) For e.g. if your cubic was instead $x^3+cx-d=0$, the rest of it would have held good.

Answer (score 3):

COMMENT.-You have maybe to specified the nature of coefficients because if not your property is not true.

Counterexample:If $f(x)=x^3-\dfrac{13}{4}x+\dfrac32$ then $f\left(\dfrac32\right)=f\left(\dfrac12\right)=f(-2)=0$ and $-2\lt d=\left(\dfrac32\right)\lt2$ and $d\ne0$

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: It is proper as an answer. If someone asks a "prove this statement" question, and the statement in the question is actually false, then a disproof of the statement qualifies as an answer. +1